# How can I store and compare two items on click for a matching game?

Tags: javascript, css

Here, I'm trying to build a memory game. In this game, I want to build logic for card Matching. Logic is something like I want to store the first click and second click in two variables and later check when a user clicks the first card and if
it will match with the second card then the user will not able to click those cards again and it will not flip. And If not match user can click those card again. Trying for an hour but can't solve it. What should I do? Anyone help, Please?

```js
// Declaring variable  

 const cardClass = ["fa-diamond", "fa-paper-plane-o", "fa-anchor", "fa-bolt"];
 const firstClick, secondClick;
 const card = document.querySelectorAll('.deck li ');

//for loop

 for(let i=0;i<card.length;i++){
     card[i].addEventListener('click', flipOver);
 }



 // flipOver function

 function flipOver(e){

    let element = e.currentTarget;
   e.target.classList.toggle("open");

}

// Card Matching logic

for(let i=0; i<cardClass.length; i++){

    if(e.target.classList.contains(cardClass[i])){
        this.click = firstClick;
    }

}
```

```css
.deck .card {
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    background: #2e3d49;
    font-size: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 5px 2px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
}

.deck .card.open {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    /* transform: rotateX(180deg); */
    background: #02b3e4;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition: .2s;
    font-size: 33px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="deck">
    <li class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card ">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card ">
        <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
    </li>
</u>
```

Comment: What's the plan with the constants? They'd normally be assigned values when they're defined. Otherwise they're probably not constants.

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/d3uxy5sw/)

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing = in const declaration`

Comment: @isherwood that's okay. But how to build the logic that I can check user first clicked and second clicked match or not! That's the main problem!

Comment: Step one is to provide us with something that doesn't error. Then we can move forward.

Comment: forget to add font awesome.Here You can check now:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusar4321/06L5cx1s/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a counter that keeps track of the number of opened cards -> if it's two cards, time to compare them.
To know what card was clicked we store a reference inside firstclick and secondClick respectively.
e.g.

```
let element = e.currentTarget;
firstClick = element;
```

To compare if two cards are of the same type we use it's className ("fa-diamond", "fa-paper-plane-o"...) we can get by calling:

```
var card1Type = firstClick.getElementsByTagName("i")[0].className;
var card2Type = secondClick.getElementsByTagName("i")[0].className;
```

If those match, remove it's click event listener:

```
  firstClick.removeEventListener("click", flipOver);
  secondClick.removeEventListener("click", flipOver);
```

If not, we need to turn them over again.

The whole example:

```js
// Declaring variable  

const cardClass = ["fa-diamond", "fa-paper-plane-o", "fa-anchor", "fa-bolt"];
var firstClick, secondClick;
var counter = 1;
var wrong = false;
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.deck li ');

//for loop

for (let i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
  card[i].addEventListener('click', flipOver);
}


function proceed() {
  firstClick.classList.toggle("open");
  secondClick.classList.toggle("open");
  wrong = false;
}

function flipOver(e) {
  if (!wrong) {
    let element = e.currentTarget;
    e.target.classList.toggle("open");
    if (counter == 1) {
      firstClick = element;
      counter = 2;
    } else if (counter == 2) {
      secondClick = element;
      var card1Type = firstClick.getElementsByTagName("i")[0].className;
      var card2Type = secondClick.getElementsByTagName("i")[0].className;
      if (card1Type == card2Type) {
        firstClick.removeEventListener("click", flipOver);
        secondClick.removeEventListener("click", flipOver);
      } else {
        wrong = true;
        setTimeout(proceed, 1000);
      }
      counter = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.deck .card {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  background: #2e3d49;
  font-size: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
}

.deck .card.open {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: #02b3e4;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-size: 33px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="deck">
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card ">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card ">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, Brother! Brother, can I do it using if else statement rather than using switch?

Comment: Glad I could help! I edited my answer above to use an if-else block instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Brother! :)

Answer (score 0):

search on google but you can use localStorage : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Because you can set and get 
is it what you want ?

Comment: I want to compare the first clicked card with the second one. 
U can check it - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusar4321/06L5cx1s/2/)

Comment: you can to add a class hidden for example and if you click twice hidden class is added and each time you click for the first time hidden class removed
You know what i mean ?